# Открыть файл на компьютере через js

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли открыть файл на компьютере через JS?
На клиенте, соответственно.

Comment: Посмотри, что-то на гите есть, [это оно](https://github.com/b5414/readFileAsync)?

Comment: Это можно сделать в некоторых версиях IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К счастью нет, иначе были бы огромные проблемы с безопасностью. JS исполняется браузером(движком), и не предоставляет JS-коду возможность проникнуть за рамки это самого браузера.

Тем не менее, у вас есть возможность взаимодействовать с файлом, если пользователь загрузит его через HTML-тег `<input type="file">`

Comment: а как я могу взаимодействовать?

Comment: находил что-то подобное


   ` WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");`
    `WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);`

это вообще что?

Comment: @justlead что, то мне подсказывает, что это node.js, не знаю, я сам не Js-er,просто знакомился, Тем не менее, т.к ссылки скорее всего нельзя выкладывать, то первая же ссылка по запросу "js работа с файлами" вам всё расскажет

Comment: @justlead, это для [wsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host), программа которой по умолчанию открываются скрипты на windows. Плюс раньше в IE можно было запускать ActiveX компоненты, то есть в ie можно было обращаться к ActiveXObject, например `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")` вместо `new XMLHttpRequest()`. Однако сейчас это убрали.